# Resize image BEFORE uploading to Azure blob storage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, blob, webimage

i am trying to resize an image using the WebImage helper BEFORE uploading to Azure blob, using the following code, but getting this error:

```
cannot convert from 'system.web.helpers.webimage' to 'system.io.stream'
```

The code is as follows:

```
    public async Task<string> UploadPropertyImageAsync(HttpPostedFileBase imageToUpload)
    {
        string imageFullPath = null;
        if (imageToUpload == null || imageToUpload.ContentLength == 0 || imageToUpload.ContentLength >= 8388608)
        {
            return null;
        }
        //Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageToUpload);
        WebImage img = new WebImage(imageToUpload.InputStream);
        if (img.Width > 1000)
            img.Resize(1000, 1000); 
        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = ConnectionString.GetConnectionString();
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("property");

            if (await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
            {
                await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(
                    new BlobContainerPermissions
                    {
                        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                    }
                    );
            }
            string imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "-" + Path.GetExtension(img.FileName);

            CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(imageName);
            cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = img.ContentType;
            await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(img);
```

Any idea where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync` expects a stream which your `WebImage` object is not and hence you're getting this error.

What you would need to do is convert the image into a stream. I looked up the documentation and there's no direct method to do so.

However you can get the bytes from the WebImage using [`WebImage.GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage.getbytes(v=vs.111).aspx) and then use [`CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromByeArrayAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfrombytearray.aspx) method to upload that byte array as blob in Azure Storage.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is pretty self explanatory.

This line is expecting a `Stream`, not a `WebImage` variable.

```
await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(img);
```

There are plenty of examples showing how to upload files to Azure, for example:

[Uploading to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597962/391605)

... and here...

[An Introduction to Windows Azure BLOB Storage](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/an-introduction-to-windows-azure-blob-storage/)

Comment: Thanks Mike. I was able to get the file to a blob, but I need to get the height and width (and possibly perform a resize first too), before I upload, hence why I introduced webimage into the mix. I'm assuming I can't resize a stream, so is my. Eat option to save to blob first and then do the resize?