# Upload archive to specific folder in Container blobs Azure

Tags: c#, azure, containers, blob

how do I upload a file to a specific folder inside the Azure container?

I'm using the code below and it's working fine, but it's saving in the container root.

```
var connectionString = "xxxxxx";
string containerName = "projects";
var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
var containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
var path2 = @"C:\2021\BlobContainer\";
var fileName2 = dados.after.NR_RA + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyHHmm") + ".txt";
var localFile = Path.Combine(path2, fileName2);
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName2);
Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage");
using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
uploadFileStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out!

As noted in this post:

[How to save a file to a subfolder in an Azure blob container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742201/how-to-save-a-file-to-a-subfolder-in-an-azure-blob-container)

It is necessary to change:

```
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName2);
```

For

```
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("Folder1/" + fileName2);
```

Getting the code like this:

```
var connectionString = "xxxxxx";
string containerName = "projects";
var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
var containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
var path2 = @"C:\2021\BlobContainer\";
var fileName2 = dados.after.NR_RA + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyHHmm") + ".txt";
var localFile = Path.Combine(path2, fileName2);
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("Folder1/" + fileName2);
Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage");
using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
uploadFileStream.Close();
```

Get the hint!!!