# Coded UI C# - How to Upload Captured Image to Azure Storage Container

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, coded-ui-tests

From a Coded UI test method, what is the way to upload a captured image into Azure Storage and not saving in local drive?

To save a captured image into a local file, I am doing the following, it works fine:

```
BrowserWindow window = new BrowserWindow();
Image cml1 = window.CaptureImage();
cml1.Save(screenshotDir + screenshotDirClickMainLinks + "1" + 
CMLelectAndNaturalGas + DateTime.Now.ToString(dateTime) + fileSuffix);
```

How to upload "cml1" into Azure Storage without saving it in a local drive? Do I convert cml1 one into a stream that can be input into an Azure storage object? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c-sharp) looks to have some info, but it does not talk about Azure Storage. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstream?view=azure-dotnet) has "UploadFromStream" method for CloudBlockBlob, but no example is given.

For Azure Storage, I know [how to create a container and upload a local file into that container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50301353/c-sharp-azure-storage-how-to-upload-a-file-to-an-already-existing-container). Here is the code segment:

```
if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount))
{
    // Get the reference of the storage blob
    CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("testresult");

     container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(localFileName);
cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(sourceFile);

// Uploading second file

CloudBlobContainer container2 = client.GetContainerReference("testresult");
            container2.CreateIfNotExists();


CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob2 = container2.GetBlockBlobReference(localFileName2);
cloudBlockBlob2.UploadFromFile(sourceFile2);
```

}

How do I use "cml1" reference to upload the captured image into Azure Storage directly without saving it into a local folder first?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output returned from `BrowserWindow.CaptureImage` is a [`System.Drawing.Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) (the type of your variable `cml1`), which you can convert to a `byte[]` using a technique such as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801289/314291), or better, compress the image to a more concise format such as `.PNG`:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

*Credit: Above code taken directly from this [StackOverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350818/314291)*

Once you have the `byte[]` array, you can then directly upload this to your `Blobstorage` container, with an approach similar to what you've tried, but using the more direct [`CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfrombytearrayasync?view=azure-dotnet).

```
public async Task SaveBlob(string containerName, string key, byte[] blobToSave)
{
  var blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
  var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
  await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
  var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(key);
  await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(blobToSave, 0, blobToSave.Length);
}
```

Where `_storageAccount` is the `CloudStorageAccount` parsed from your Azure Storage account connection string, `containerName` is the (lowercase) name of the container (folder), `key` is a unique filename for your image, and of course `blobToSave` is the byte array you've just converted.

Performance note - if you are storing multiple blobs to the same container reference, that you won't want to do the `CreateIfNotExists(Async)` check each time - ideally, do a one-off check at bootstrap time when your app or test is launched.

Comment: Further to performance, if you are uploading a large number of blobs consecutively, you can retain and reuse the `blobContainer` reference. I'm not 100% sure of the thread safety, if you intend parallelizing uploads.

Comment: Thank you very much StuartLC for giving me detail answer that I sincerely appreciate. I will check your solution in detail and will update my code.

Comment: Thanks again StuartLC. I am able to update my code with your help. Great response!