# Why CloudBlobClient does not contain a definition for GetBlockBlobReference?

Tags: c#, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a file to a new container of a Blob following this [Example](https://markheath.net/post/how-to-use-azure-blob-storage-with).

I am creating the container like this and looks fine.

```
var blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference("productimages");
if (container.CreateIfNotExists())
{
    var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
    permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
    container.SetPermissions(permissions);
}
```

But trying to call the GetBlockBlobReference from a CloudBlobContainer shows me that the method doesn't exist.

```
string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("productimages/image_{0}{1}", guid, ext);
CloudBlockBlob blob = blobStorage.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
```

I have been trying to obtain documentation about the method, but it looks like is no longer avaliable in [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblockblobreference).
I think than I am doing somethign fool. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found aditional problems in my solution including the one mentioned by nlawalker. After updating Windows.Storage at the end I solved my problem based in the most upvoted answer of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597043/upload-a-single-file-to-blob-storage-azure)

Comment: This is now null and void when using .NET Core 3.1 because Microsoft has once again, in it's unknown wisdom, decided to refactor the Azure API's into yet another complicated structure. I should know as I am currently trying to upgrade an API from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1! What a pain with all the unnecessary changes!

Answer (score 0):

`GetBlockBlobReference` is a method on `CloudBlobContainer`. The documentation for this method is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblockblobreference?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: My wrong, the method is from CloudBlobContainer still somehow isn't showing

Comment: You are calling `GetBlockBlobReference` on `blobStorage`, and from the code you added in your edit it appears that `blobStorage` is a `CloudBlobClient`, not `CloudBlobContainer`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!