# How to transform xml data using datafactory pipeline

Tags: xml, azure-data-factory

**How do we save data inside of an XML payload to blob storage?**

**input**

```
<root>
  <alexIsAwesome>yes he is</alexIsAwesome>
  <bytes>sdfsdfjijOIJOISJDFQPWORPJkjsdlfkjlksdf==</bytes>
</root>
```

**desired result**

```
<root>
  <alexIsAwesome>yes he is</alexIsAwesome>
  <bytes>/blob/path/toSavedPayload</bytes>
</root>
```

1. save bytes somewhere in blob
2. replace bytes with URI of where bytes were saved

**How do we use data factory to extract a node from XML and save it to blob?**

Comment: Need a bit more info - define the XML payload?  Do you mean it's a file in data lake or is returned in the ADF pipeline from a web or database call?

Comment: xml blob is stored in a storage account, i'm looking for functionality that is similar to a regular XSLT transform

Comment: I used Azure Batch Custom Activity to solve this problem. Here is another SO answer where I mentioned that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59938374/converting-xml-files-to-json-or-csv

Answer (score 2):

Currently, ADF doesn’t support XML natively. But

1. You may write your own code and then use [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) of ADF.
2. SSIS has built-in support for [XML as a source](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3141/importing-xml-documents-using-sql-server-integration-services/). Maybe you could take a look.

Comment: just wondering, why are you mentioning SSIS? are you saying we can export from SSIS and import into ADF?

Comment: Yes, you can "lift and shift" your existing SSIS packages to a cloud instance of integration services. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @MartinEstebanZurita would love an example of an SSIS package that does an XML transform and then how that can be lifted and shifted into ADF

Comment: XML is now supported in ADF ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml

Answer (score 2):

For that case you have to use some custom code to do this. I would choose from these options

- Azure Functions - only for some simple data processing
- Azure Databricks - in the case you need to process some big XML data

Comment: XML is now supported in ADF ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml

Answer (score 2):

As Azure Data Factory does not support XML natively, I would suggest you to go for SSIS package.

1. In the Data flow task, have XML source and read bytes from the xml into a variable of DT_Image datatype.
2. Create a script task, which uploads the byte array (DT_Image) got in step no.1 to azure blob storage as mentioned in the below. Code slightly modified for the requirement. [Reference of SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597043/upload-a-single-file-to-blob-storage-azure)

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;    

// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("StorageKey");

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

byte[] byteArrayIn = Dts.Variables["User::ImageVariable"].Value;

// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);)
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
}
```

3. Now, host this SSIS Package in SSIS Runtime in Azure Data Factory and execute the SSIS package.

[SSIS Runtime in Azure DataFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime)

Comment: XML is now supported in ADF ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml