# Best way to run .exe file in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, exe, azure-container-instances

I have an .exe application that outputs a file into the folder path you give as an input. The end goal is to get the output file into blob storage.

I have considered azure functions but not sure if it is possible to provide it with a folder path ... anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run an .exe application in Azure, you can use Azure Functions. You can use an Azure Function to trigger the .exe application to run, and then use another Azure Function to get the output file from the application and store it in blob storage.

Comment: although this only works when I manually create the functions, deploying from vs code means the root folder becomes read only

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package

Comment: When you run from a package, the wwwroot folder becomes read-only and you'll receive an error when writing files to this directory. Files are also read-only in the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish your task in Azure Functions, but it does not run an exe. For that, you need [Azure Batch to execute custom activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68265811/cusom-activity-in-azure-data-factory/68286820#68286820).