# Azure Data Factory : Transform XML Data to JSON

Tags: json, xml, azure, azure-data-factory

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere as I've been searching the forum but still haven't come across anything similar. Also, I am sorry if my question is in layman terms as I just started working on Azure and many things and terminologies are still very new to me. So here's the situation,

**BACKGROUND**

I am using a WebActivity called **GetBearerToken** which requests an API end-point to retrieve Authentication token (JSON Response). This token is then passed as part of the Header for the next WebActivity (i.e., Bearer Token Authorization) requesting Data from 2nd API end-point. Getting the Bearer token like this,

[image: GetData WebActivity Settings]

The Pipeline looks something like this,

[image: WebActivity to GetData from API Endpoint]

The response I'm getting is in XML format. Since Azure isn't very helpful when it comes to XML content, I was looking to transform the data in JSON so that it could be Parsed or stored in the next steps.

I've searched a lot and then came across something like this,

```
@json(xml(activity('GetData').output.Response))
```

It's been suggested somewhere that it takes the XML response from the WebActivity and converts it into JSON.

**QUESTION**

Now my question is, since I'm fairly new so I am not sure where I need to use this command for it to work, apologies it might be a very simple 1 line answer but I am completely clueless how and where to use these commands? Do I need to create a new WebActivity or similar where it could handle this.

Any suggestion and help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot and Looking forward to some helpful tips and suggestions

Comment: I'm not 100% it can be done on ADF directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231314/1384539

Comment: Can you show us the whole pipeline overview?