# Upload blob to Azure and give public read access C#

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I'm trying to upload an image to Azure blob storage to view later in my application.
However, when I uploaded my image I can not view the image using the link of my blob as I think the file-view permissions are not set correctly.
But, I do not know how to set these in code.

I have found a question with an answer that is similar, but it's so outdated that it does not work like that anymore.

([Link of the old similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597043/upload-a-single-file-to-blob-storage-azure))

In the following block you can find a piece of my code that creates a container (if it does not exist => create one), in eather way, if it exists or not, yet it should be set accessible for anyone to read/view the uploaded blob.

```
        public async Task<BlobContainerClient> CreateContainerAsync(string containerName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(containerName))
            throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(containerName)}' cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(containerName));

        var container = new BlobContainerClient(_connectionString, containerName);
         //Here I want to set the access policy but I'm not sure on how to implement it
        //await container.SetAccessPolicyAsync(PublicAccess = Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.PublicAccessType.Blob);

        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        return container;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.createifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#microsoft-azure-storage-blob-cloudblobcontainer-createifnotexistsasync(microsoft-azure-storage-blob-blobcontainerpublicaccesstype-microsoft-azure-storage-blob-blobrequestoptions-microsoft-azure-storage-operationcontext)) could help you? You are able to pass [BlobContainerPublicAccessType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobcontainerpublicaccesstype?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)

Comment: @JochemVanHespen - Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @GauravMantri Done, I always try and comment first to see if I understood the question correctly but since no real response is given I guess we can assume this is the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested ^^

[CreateIfNotExistsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.createifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.createifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#microsoft-azure-storage-blob-cloudblobcontainer-createifnotexistsasync(microsoft-azure-storage-blob-blobcontainerpublicaccesstype-microsoft-azure-storage-blob-blobrequestoptions-microsoft-azure-storage-operationcontext)) which allows you to pass [BlobContainerPublicAccessType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobcontainerpublicaccesstype?view=azure-dotnet-legacy).

This Enum enables you to specific the access type of the created containers.

Alternatively you can also adjust this through [Azure](https://www.portal.azure.com) in case your container has already been created and you have the required access (check through Access Control (IAM)) by navigating to the container and then pressing following button:

[image: Change access level]

You will see the options it gives you will map directly to the BlobContainerPublicAccessType